# How to reassign values in an array while avoiding Index Out Of Bounds

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a List of  that looks something like this:

```
"StudentA, Math, Mrs.Jones, Sixth, 98, 92, 90, , 40"
"StudentB, Science, Mrs.Williams, Second, , 91, 70, 50, 41"
"StudentC, History, Mr.Webber, Eighth, 100, 92, 90, 75, 40"
"StudentD, Art, Mrs.Gonzalez, Fourth, 99, 91, 85,, 40"
```

What I want to do is this: for every blank record (i.e. a comma with no value - 90,,40. The second comma is a blank record), I want to default it to 0.

In my attempt, I keep getting Index Out of Bounds Exceptions. This is my attempt:

```
foreach (string element in studentList)
{
   string[] studentSplit = element.Split(',');
   studentSplit[Array.IndexOf(studentSplit, "")] = "0";
}
```

The code will work on the first iteration but crash after any subsequent iterations. I am not sure why this is an index out of bounds exception, however. I am not allocating a size. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should really create a `Student` class and use a `List<Student>`.  Parse each input string into an instance of your class.  Use nullable `int`s for the fields.  This approach is torturing a perfectly-good object oriented programming language.

Comment: Is there a way to handle this within my existing loop?

Comment: @Cuphead You do not know how to test for a value less than 0?

Comment: I  was just seeing if I could do this without nested loops.

Comment: See my (down voted) answer.

Comment: Let me see. I can't down-vote.

Comment: You accepted a less efficient answer than mine.  You asked how to do it without nested loops.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem you're having is that if there's no occurrence of "" in your studentSplit array, Array.IndexOf(studentSplit, "") returns a -1, which is out of bounds for the studentSplit array. And the "" is actually a " ".

Try this:

```
        foreach (string element in studentList)
        {
            string[] studentSplit = element.Split(',');
            for (int i = 0; i < studentSplit.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                studentSplit[i] = studentSplit[i] == " " ? "0" : studentSplit[i];
            }
        }
```

Comment: This will not work if input is  like "" which is exactly StudentD row

Comment: Testing `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( studentSplit[i] )` will cope with multiple (or no) spaces.  Using `if` rather than `?` will more obviously signal to the reader that no action is taken if the string is not null or white space.

Comment: @DebashishSaha That's incorrect. I ran it myself and the split on Student D row returns a " ", not a "".

Comment: @FrankBoyne Yeah, you're right. My solution only addresses the given data set format.

Comment: @phil I don't get the same results you do.  Note the absence of a 0 between 85 and 40 on the fourth line.  https://www.ideone.com/nCATxP

Comment: you are only checking for " " which is string length of 1 .what about "" string length of 0 ? how come you are not getting exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> s = new List<string>();
        s.Add("StudentA, Math, Mrs.Jones, Sixth, 98, 92, 90, , 40");
        s.Add("StudentB, Science, Mrs.Williams, Second, , 91, 70, 50, 41");
        s.Add("StudentC, History, Mr.Webber, Eighth, 100, 92, 90, 75, 40");
        s.Add("StudentD, Art, Mrs.Gonzalez, Fourth, 99, 91, 85,, 40");
        foreach (var item in s)
        {
                string[] studentSplit = item.Split(',');
            studentSplit.Where(x => x.Trim().Length==0).ToList().ForEach(y=>studentSplit[Array.LastIndexOf(studentSplit, y)]="0");

        }
```

This Will do the Job.
Now answering your question

> I keep getting Index Out of Bounds Exceptions

Because Array.IndexOf will give you -1 if not Found.Array[-1] will give you OutofBound Exception

Just an Advice always use trim function for string input.If you are handling this kind of scenarion where you need index of.Use ToUpper case also at safe side

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (string element in studentList)
{
    string[] studentSplit = element.Split(',');
    studentSplit[Array.IndexOf(studentSplit, "")] = "0";
}
```

The problem with this aproach is that you are looking for a "", and most of the blank spaces you are trying to find are " ".

One solution could be to iterate studentSplit and check with each string, adding a Replace(" ","") on the comparisson, as so...

```
for(int i = 0; i < studentSplit.Length; i++)
{
     studentSplit[i] = studentSplit[i].Replace(" ","").Equals("") ? "0" : studentSplit[i];
}
```

That should do what you need and it works for "" and " ".

Answer (score -1):

There's actually quite a few things wrong with this code.

```
foreach (string element in studentList)
{
    string[] studentSplit = element.Split(',');
    studentSplit[Array.IndexOf(studentSplit, "")] = "0";
}
```

You're looping through each student, which is fine. You are then creating an array of the student values via `Split(...)`, which is fine. but then you're looking for an empty string *inside* the individual student values (the results of the split), which looks very weird. Am I correct in thinking this is your check to see if that student value is empty? If so, this is the wrong way to go about this since you're not accounting for whitespace. You then use that index (the index of a character in the student value) as the accessor index for your student parts. That makes zero sense to me, and I can only assume you've meant to access the index of that character in the full student string, not access the part itself. Since those domains don't match up (index in student part vs index in student), you're bound to end up with an `IndexOutOfBoundException`.

Basically, the premise of the algorythm is wrong in that you are not accounting for the offset of each student value within the full student text, and that you are failing to account for white space.

So here's a different way of going about this. I'm not saying it's the best. I'm just saying I think this is more in line with what you're looking for.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
            var students =
                new [] {
                    "StudentA, Math, Mrs.Jones, Sixth, 98, 92, 90, , 40",
                    "StudentB, Science, Mrs.Williams, Second, , 91, 70, 50, 41",
                    "StudentC, History, Mr.Webber, Eighth, 100, 92, 90, 75, 40",
                    "StudentD, Art, Mrs.Gonzalez, Fourth, 99, 91, 85,, 40"
                };

        foreach (var student in WithDefaultStudentValues(students))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(student);
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<string> WithDefaultStudentValues(IEnumerable<string> students)
    {
        foreach (var student in students)
        {
            var studentValues =
                student
                    .Split(',')
                    .Select(value => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) ? "0" : value);

            yield return string.Join(",", studentValues);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If it is not found the index will be -1 which is out of bounds.

```
int ind;
while((ind = Array.IndexOf(ssplit, "")) >= 0)
{
    ssplit[ind] = "fix";
}
```

Comment: How does this show "How to reassign values in an array while avoiding Index Out Of Bounds"?

Comment: @rory.ap You don't assign a value when the index is out of bound.  This is a direct answer to "I am not sure why this is an index out of bounds exception, however."